# Going through x86 assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86

I need some help determining what these lines of x86 assembly language do. After the 2nd lea, will %eax always be 5 and does %ebx become 4? Also I'm not sure what the add and compare do. Any help is appreciated.

```
       mov    $0x5,%eax
       lea    -0x20(%ebp),%esi
       lea    -0x1(%eax),%ebx
       add    0x4(%esi,%ebx,4),%eax
       cmp    %eax,(%esi,%ebx,4)
       je     0x8048dce
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mov    $0x5,%eax             - sets eax to 5
lea    -0x20(%ebp),%esi      - loads the dword value at ebp-0x20 into esi
lea    -0x1(%eax),%ebx       - sets ebx to the value of eax-1 (i.e. 4)
add    0x4(%esi,%ebx,4),%eax - adds the dword value at esi+ebx*4+4 to eax
cmp    %eax,(%esi,%ebx,4)    - compares eax to the dword value at esi+ebx*4
je     0x8048dce             - branches if they are equal
```

Comment: Hmm... Seems to be equivalent to `lea eax,[ebp + 5]`, `cmp [ebp - 4],eax`, `je  ...`. Pretty interesting.